How to prevent label overflow in React Native Gifted Charts BarChart?
I'm using the BarChart component from react-native-gifted-charts to display some data in my React Native app. However, I'm facing an issue where the labels on the x-axis are overflowing and getting cut off.
here is the code I tried so far
import { BarChart } from 'react-native-gifted-charts';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const nutrients = [
    { label: 'Calories', value: 81 },
    { label: 'Carbohydrates', value: 56 },
    { label: 'Fat', value: 45 },
    { label: 'Protein', value: 0.4 },
    { label: 'Sugar', value: 0.1 },
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <BarChart
        showValuesAsTopLabel
        horizontal
        hideRules
        barWidth={10}
        barBorderRadius={4}
        frontColor="lightgray"
        data={nutrients}
        yAxisThickness={0}
        xAxisThickness={0}
        hideYAxisText
        xAxisLabelsVerticalShift={20}
        labelsExtraHeight={20}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

https://snack.expo.dev/kAIinbKfvt1viem9v9JFF

This can be fixed using the labelWidth and xAxisLabelTextStyle props.
Here's my snack with the above props- https://snack.expo.dev/@ak_97/hot-indigo-cookie
Same issue has been reported on the Github issues page of the library.
